# Converting Nested XML to Dataframe in R

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert XML data from [clinicaltrials.gov](https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=&fields=NCTId%2C+OrgFullName%2C+BriefTitle%2C+StartDate%2C+Condition%2C+Keyword%2C+InterventionName%2C+EnrollmentCount%2C+LocationFacility%2C+LocationCity%2C+LocationState%2C+LocationZip%2C+LocationCountry&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=1000&fmt=xml) into a dataframe for analysis in **R**. I have the URL that allows me to select the specific fields I'm looking for within each study. Each row and NCTId is an individual study, which may be held at multiple facilities and locations. Because of this there will be multiple responses in facility and location columns of a single observation.

My first attempt successfully converted the data into a df but made for difficult cleaning with sometimes hundreds of facility and location values packed into one field for a single study and no delimiter (attempted space but too many facilities, cities and countries (more than just US included) with two plus words and a space).

Code:

```r
url1 <- "https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=&fields=NCTId%2C+OrgFullName%2C+BriefTitle%2C+StartDate%2C+Condition%2C+Keyword%2C+InterventionName%2C+EnrollmentCount%2C+LocationFacility%2C+LocationCity%2C+LocationState%2C+LocationZip%2C+LocationCountry&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=1000&fmt=xml"
dat1 <- read_xml(url1)
dat_xml1 <- xmlParse(dat1)
df1 <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(dat_xml1, "//StudyFields"))
```

Result: *(example of issue)*

```
glimpse(df1[13, 10:13])
Rows: 1
Columns: 4
$ city    <chr> "ScottsdaleJacksonvilleAlbert LeaMankatoRochesterEau ClaireLa Crosse"
$ state   <chr> "ArizonaFloridaMinnesotaMinnesotaMinnesotaWisconsinWisconsin"
$ zip     <chr> "8525932224-99805600756001559055470154601"
$ country <chr> "United StatesUnited StatesUnited StatesUnited StatesUnited StatesUnited StatesUnited States"
```

After some attempts at cleaning, I returned to try and fix the problem upon import and unnest the listed values within each column:

Code:

```r
url1 <- "https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=&fields=NCTId%2C+OrgFullName%2C+BriefTitle%2C+StartDate%2C+Condition%2C+Keyword%2C+InterventionName%2C+EnrollmentCount%2C+LocationFacility%2C+LocationCity%2C+LocationState%2C+LocationZip%2C+LocationCountry&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=1000&fmt=xml"
dat1 <- as_list(read_xml(url1))
xml_df <- as_tibble(dat1) %>%
  unnest_longer(StudyFieldsResponse)

dat_wide <- xml_df %>%
  filter(StudyFieldsResponse_id == "StudyFields") %>%
  unnest_wider(StudyFieldsResponse, names_repair = "unique")

dat_df <- dat_wide %>%
  unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%
  unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%
  type_convert()
```

In my `dat_wide` object I can see that the multiple responses within one field are listed separately, so I feel as though this is the right path.

```
glimpse(dat_wide[206, 10:13])
Rows: 1
Columns: 4
$ city    <list> [["Kansas City"], ["Columbus"]]
$ state   <list> [["Kansas"], ["Ohio"]]
$ zip     <list> [["66160"], ["43210"]]
$ country <list> [["United States"], ["United States"]]
```

However, when I move to the final step of unnesting the values in each cell, I get an error:

```
dat_df <- dat_wide %>%
+   unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%
+   unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%
+   type_convert()
Error in `unnest()`:
! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 4 to size 5.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Ultimately, I'd like to unnest and pivot these values so that individual studies with multiple locations will have as many rows. I appreciate any help you can offer with this issue.

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more information about your goal result. Are you only interested in the study locations? The challenge here is that the nesting isn't especially clean, so you'll have to be a lot more specific about what the output format should look like. Study #6 (Ziltivekimab) is a good example of this: it has one study but two "treatments", two "conditions", 116 locations (only 45 of which have a "state" associated with them). Would you want each entry duplicated (so that theres 116*2*2*45 rows)? Or do you just want the "location" of each study?

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up - I would want each entry duplicated for fields with multiple values. The location data was just the example I chose.

Comment: BTW, you can change output format and get a flat CSV directly from API, it's controlled by that last parameter in query string, `fmt=xml` .  You can try with `readr::read_csv("https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=&fields=NCTId%2C+OrgFullName%2C+BriefTitle%2C+StartDate%2C+Condition%2C+Keyword%2C+InterventionName%2C+EnrollmentCount%2C+LocationFacility%2C+LocationCity%2C+LocationState%2C+LocationZip%2C+LocationCountry&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=1000&fmt=csv", skip = 9)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach to convert the XML file to a "tidy" tibble, where fields with multiple responses are stored as list columns which still require some additional unnesting.

Note: Updated to account for multiple responses. (Thx to @Dubukay for pointing that out).

```r
url1 <- "https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=&fields=NCTId%2C+OrgFullName%2C+BriefTitle%2C+StartDate%2C+Condition%2C+Keyword%2C+InterventionName%2C+EnrollmentCount%2C+LocationFacility%2C+LocationCity%2C+LocationState%2C+LocationZip%2C+LocationCountry&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=1000&fmt=xml"

library(xml2)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

dat1 <- read_xml(url1)

dat2 <- dat1 |>
  as_list() |>
  pluck("StudyFieldsResponse")

field_names <- vapply(dat2$FieldList, `[[`, 1,
  FUN.VALUE = character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE
)

dat3 <- lapply(
  dat2$StudyFieldsList,
  \(x) {
    lapply(
      x,
      \(x) {
        field_value <- vapply(x, `[[`, 1,
          FUN.VALUE = character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE
        )
        return(list(field_value))
      }
    ) |>
      setNames(field_names) |>
      as_tibble()
  }
) |>
  list_rbind()

dat3[] <- dat3 |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    if (all(lengths(x) == 1)) {
      x <- unlist(x)
    }
    x
  })

head(dat3)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 13
#>   NCTId      OrgFullName BriefTitle StartDate Condition Keyword InterventionName
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <list>    <list>    <list>  <list>          
#> 1 NCT062002… Toros Univ… Effect of… <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr>   <chr [1]>       
#> 2 NCT062002… Thompson C… Reduction… <chr [1]> <chr [3]> <chr>   <chr [2]>       
#> 3 NCT062002… St. Olavs … Cardio-va… <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr>   <chr [0]>       
#> 4 NCT062002… Samsung Me… Rivoceran… <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr>   <chr [1]>       
#> 5 NCT062002… Poitiers U… Patients … <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr>   <chr [1]>       
#> 6 NCT062002… Novo Nordi… A Researc… <chr [1]> <chr [2]> <chr>   <chr [2]>       
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: EnrollmentCount <list>, LocationFacility <list>,
#> #   LocationCity <list>, LocationState <list>, LocationZip <list>,
#> #   LocationCountry <list>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this looks like it only grabs the first entry of each. You can pull up the XML doc in a web browser by navigating to the URL where you can see that the sixth entry (for example) has additional locations and conditions.

Comment: Thx @Dubukay. Already guessed that I missed something. Now updated to account for multiple field values.

Comment: Nice. This feels like the way to get it as tidy as possible because I don't think duplicate study rows are possible with variable-length entries. Unnesting can then be done on columns independently based on the question of interest.

Comment: @Dubukay. Yup. Agree. Don't see any option to unnest into true tidy format.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it in a single pipeline. It replaces empty values with `NA` on concatenates multiple entries with a comma:

```r
library(xml2)

res <- paste0("https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields",
               "?expr=&fields=NCTId%2C+OrgFullName%2C+BriefTitle%2C+",
               "StartDate%2C+Condition%2C+Keyword%2C+InterventionName%2C+",
               "EnrollmentCount%2C+LocationFacility%2C+LocationCity%2C+",
               "LocationState%2C+LocationZip%2C+",
               "LocationCountry&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=1000&fmt=xml") |> 
  read_xml() |>
  xml_find_first("StudyFieldsList") |>
  xml_children() |>
  lapply(\(x) 
    as_list(x) |> unname() |> lapply(unlist) |> lapply(unname) |>
      lapply(\(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x) |> lapply(paste, collapse = ", ") |>
      setNames(as_list(x) |> lapply(attr, "Field") |> unname() |> unlist()) |>
      dplyr::as_tibble()) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()
```

The result is:

```r
res
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 13
#>    NCTId     OrgFullName BriefTitle StartDate Condition Keyword InterventionName
#>    <chr>     <chr>       <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr>           
#>  1 NCT06200~ Toros Univ~ Effect of~ December~ Healthy ~ Carob ~ Germ and Carob ~
#>  2 NCT06200~ Thompson C~ Reduction~ January ~ Prostate~ NA      Spot Delete pla~
#>  3 NCT06200~ St. Olavs ~ Cardio-va~ October ~ Heart Fa~ NA      NA              
#>  4 NCT06200~ Samsung Me~ Rivoceran~ March 1,~ Thymic E~ NA      Rivoceranib     
#>  5 NCT06200~ Poitiers U~ Patients ~ December~ Waldenst~ NA      Venetoclax      
#>  6 NCT06200~ Novo Nordi~ A Researc~ April 1,~ Heart Fa~ NA      Ziltivekimab, P~
#>  7 NCT06200~ National Y~ Early Int~ August 1~ Premyopi~ NA      MiyoSmart Spect~
#>  8 NCT06200~ M.D. Ander~ Effect of~ June 30,~ Misuse, ~ NA      Olanzapine, Ola~
#>  9 NCT06200~ Affiliated~ Electroac~ December~ Electroa~ electr~ Electroacupunct~
#> 10 NCT06200~ M.D. Ander~ TRIP - TR~ June 30,~ Depressi~ NA      Psilocybin, Nia~
#> # i 990 more rows
#> # i 6 more variables: EnrollmentCount <chr>, LocationFacility <chr>,
#> #   LocationCity <chr>, LocationState <chr>, LocationZip <chr>,
#> #   LocationCountry <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>